# Jquery slideUp() function needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {      

    //Execute the slideShow
    slideShow();

});

function slideShow() {

    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('#gallery a').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
    $('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.2});


    //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('gallery()',5000);

}

function gallery() {

    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery a.show')?  $('#gallery a.show') : $('#gallery a:first'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption'))? $('#gallery a:first') :current.next()) : $('#gallery a:first'));   


    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({opacity: 2.0}, 2500);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show');




}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="gallery">

    <a href="#" class="show">
        <image src="" alt="fig1" width="960" height="170" />
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <image src="" alt="fig2" width="960" height="170" />
    </a>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me to find a way to make this slider slideup() and slidedown() without using a clickfunction? 
So now it's just fading in and out, but I want to make it that way that the next shown image slides up and pushes the previous away (to the top).
Thanks a lot

Comment: Green is for the accepted ones. You should see a white *V* next to answers of your previous questions.. and you should click the appropriate one.

Comment: Also, can you set an example at the jsfiddle.net because we need to see your html/css to be able to suggest a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a wrapped element around your gallery that has `position:relative` or `absolute` and `overflow:hidden` and that your images inside there are `position:absolute`.

- position the next slide to have `top` to the height of the gallery element.
- animate the current slide to have `top` to - the height of the gallery.
- animate the next slide to have `top` 0

---

```
var galleryHeight = $('#gallery').height();
next.css('top',galleryHeight + 'px');
current.animate({top: -galleryHeight + 'px', opacity:0});
next.animate({top: 0 + 'px', opacity:1});
```

Also opacity goes from 0 to 1 so using 1.2 is kind of wrong..

Comment: I just added the following lines to make it work:
to function slideShow() I added
$('#gallery a').css("top","170px");

and tot function gallery:
current.animate({top: "-170px"});
 current.removeClass('show');
 

 //Hide the current image
 
 next.css("top","170px");
 next.addClass('show');
 next.show();
 next.animate({top:"0px"});

Answer (score 0):

I can clean this up for you a bit (quick and dirty), but is this generally what you are looking to do?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {      

    //Execute the slideShow
    slideShow();

});

function slideShow() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0

    $('#gallery a').css({opacity: 0.0}).show();

    //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
    $('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.2}).show();


    //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('gallery()',5000);

}

function move() {
    $('#gallery a:first').appendTo('#gallery');
}

function gallery() {

    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery a.show')?  $('#gallery a.show') : $('#gallery a:first'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    //var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption'))? $('#gallery a:first') :current.next()) : $('#gallery a:first'));   
    var next = current.next();

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show').show()
    .animate({opacity: 2.0}, 2500);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show').slideUp(500);
    setTimeout('move()', 1500);





}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="gallery">

    <a id="t1" href="#" class="show">
        <image src="" alt="fig1" width="960" height="170" />
    </a>

    <a id="t2" href="#">
        <image src="" alt="fig2" width="960" height="170" />
    </a>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```